# how to stop animation when mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate

I am using this script for an automatic scrolling sidebar when scrolling on the page. This works fine, but I also want to achieve 2 things more:

1. when mouseover over the sidebar, the animation must stop (moving up or down). How can I make this possible?
2. the sidebar should start moving after 2 seconds when scrolling ( so a delay of 2 seconds  before moving up or down)

   ```
   $(function() {
   var offset = $("aside.page-sidebar").offset();
   var topPadding = 15;

   $(window).scroll(function() {

   if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {

       $("aside.page-sidebar").stop().animate({
           marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top +  topPadding
       },{
           duration: 5000
       });
   } else {
       $("aside.page-sidebar").stop().animate({
           marginTop: 0
       },{
           duration: 5000
       });
     };
    });
   });
   ```

Comment: Can you include more of the code? Perhaps as a codepen or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#element').hover(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$("aside.page-sidebar").stop(true,true);
});
```